# different ways of returning array types (data returned via graphql)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, graphql

I have a working function that looks like this:

```
  const handleClickOnFavouriteLocation = (item: any) => {
    console.log('MY COORD', item.coordinates);
    if(data){
      console.log('DATA COORD', data.personalFavouritePlaces.nodes[0].center.coordinates);
    }
    const addressDetails = {
      placeName: item.street,
      coordinates: item.coordinates,
    };
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    chooseLocation(addressDetails);
  };
```

Currently, the item here is hard-coded and it works. However, I am trying to replace the hardcoded item with items returned via grapqhl. However, I get an error in the coordinates field.

For example, If I check `item.coordinates` on the log, I see this. The length is 2:

```
MY COORD (2) [8.217462, 53.13975]

(2) [8.217462, 53.13975]
0: 8.217462
1: 53.13975
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

However, when I check an example of the coordinates returned from graphql, I see this:

```
DATA COORD [Array(2)]

DATA COORD 
[Array(2)]
0: (2) [8.183364, 53.157753]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The length here is 1. Even though both of them seem to be the same thing. How can I change the grahql returned data (coordinates field) such that it can be used exactly like the hard-coded one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that because the graphql is returning a one item long array with the first item containing the required array so just use `item.coordinates[0]` to use it as the same as the hard coded item